# ItemBackground in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'd like to customoze ActionBarSherlock. So, I tried to use selector for ActionButton with transparent background. This is selector code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/nav_bouton_recherche_pushed"/>
    <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/nav_bouton_recherche"/>
</selector>
```

This is menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/selection_menu_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/search_button_selector"
            android:title="@string/action_bar_search"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            />
</menu>
```

When I press any Action Button, its background changes to blue.
I tried to change default background to transparent. This is my style:

```
<style name="Theme.MyStyle" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
     <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyStyle.ActionBar</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyStyle.ActionBar</item>
     <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I met a following problem: if I press the Action Button immediately after application start, then it works fine! But later, if I press the Overflow Button, then Action Button will cease to change drawable when I press it.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In XML file is only attribute android:icon which allows you to use icon, but not selector and on this menu should be created in the code.
Override onCreateOptionsMenu in which to create the desired menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    SubMenu subMenu = menu.addSubMenu("one");
    subMenu.add("one_one");
    MenuItem item = subMenu.getItem();
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.test_selector);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

test.selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/test_shape_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/test_shape"
    android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

Comment: You also need to add some description with code ;-).... Welcome to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)